# VPS Ram Usage , the ram in use is Different to sum of memory used by processes

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, memory-usage

I start my virtual server from yesterday and move my sites to it.
There is one problem which I can’t understand it.
Task manager shows the Ram in use is 7.5 GB, it is very high for server status while in last server this web sites uses 3 GB ram only.
I check all process on server and calculate sum of their memory usage : it was not equals to RAM usage report , sum of process memory usage was about 2 GB.
If I end all process still there is many RAM in use.
If I restart server for awhile ( 2 hours ) every things are ok and then usages increase .
Is every things ok On server? Is this a software problem? Can you please tell me how can I find the solution?

Thanks
Mehdi

using this thread [Memory usage on Server 2008 keeps increasing without showing what is using the RAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/154702/memory-usage-on-server-2008-keeps-increasing-without-showing-what-is-using-the-ra) 
I find that the mysql database server use my RAM

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is being used as cache. It's perfectly normal for systems to fill all available memory with cache.

Answer (score 0):

Update to 2008 R2 - the resource manager there has a WAY more detailed analysis of the RAM usage.,... and any other resource usage you can imagin (io, cpu etc.).